# Is it possible to choose at runtime to import uic compiled files or dynamically load the ui with QUiLoader()?

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

As stated in the [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/basictutorial/uifiles.html) there are 2 ways of importing `.ui` files in your code:

- [Option A: Generating a Python class](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/basictutorial/uifiles.html#option-a-generating-a-python-class)
- [Option B: Loading it directly](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/basictutorial/uifiles.html#option-b-loading-it-directly)

In my project I'm using Option A, but now I'm wondering if it would be possible to choose **at a project level** Option A or Option B **at runtime**, because it would avoid having to compile the widgets after each change while in development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of Qt for Python the option is to use [`loadUiType`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtUiTools/loadUiType.html):

```py
ui_class, qt_class = loadUiType("filename.ui")

class FooWidget(QFooWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = ui_class()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

Comment: Thank you, I needed that in the wrapper I'm making